# Failed to find command append_branch

Tags: kamailio

I am a new user to kamailio. I am trying to use the fork.cfg to send sip registration to 2 destination. I get the following error but I have added loadmodule tm.so, why am I still getting this error?

```
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3295]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command append_branch (params 1)
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: : <core> [cfg.y:3435]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/fork.cfg, line 45, column 43: unknown command, mi
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: ERROR: bad config file (1 errors)
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: loading modules under config path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kamailio/modules
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: loading modules under config path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kamailio/modules/
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 kamailio[14065]: INFO: <core> [sctp_core.c:53]: sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 systemd[1]: kamailio.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Mar 22 15:53:48 emps116 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kamailio (OpenSER) - the Open Source SIP Server.
```

My script looks like this (default one):

```
mpath="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kamailio/modules"


loadmodule "sl.so"
loadmodule "tm.so"
.
.
.
.
route{
        # for testing purposes, simply okay all REGISTERs
        if (method=="REGISTER") {
                log("REGISTER");
                sl_send_reply("200", "ok");
                exit;
        };
        # try these two destinations first in parallel; the second
        # destination is targeted to sink port -- that will make ser
        # wait until timer hits
        seturi("sip:nobody@kamailio.org");
        append_branch("sip:parallel@kamailio.org");
        # if we do not get a positive reply, continue at reply_route[1]
        #t_on_failure("1");
        # forward the request to all destinations in destination set now
        t_relay();
}
```

Which module do I exactly need to get append_branch working?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: never mind..i found corex module is the one :)

Answer (score 1):

The append_branch() function used to be in the core, but it was moved to corex module since couple of versions ago:

- https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/corex.html#corex.f.append_branch

Whenever you don't know where a function (or other config elements) resides, look at the alphabetic indexes in the kamailio.org wiki:

- https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/#alphabetic_indexes
- https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/alphaindexes/devel/modfunctions